# Plotting Logistic Regression with a control variable

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a logistic regression graph using a control variable, but I am having some trouble finding a code for that.

#Data frame with hp in ascending order

```
Predicted_data <- data.frame(x_variable=seq(
    min(mydataframe$x_variable), max(mydataframe$x_variable),len=500))

# Fill predicted values using regression model
Predicted_data$dataframe = predict(regressionmodel, Predicted_data, type="response")`
# Plot Predicted data and original data points
plot(y_variable ~ x_variable+controlvariable, data=dataframe)
    lines(y_variable ~ x_variable+controlvariable, Predicted_data, lwd=2, col="red")
    ggplot(mydataframe, aes(x=xvariable+controlvariable, y=dependentvariable)) + geom_point(position    =    position_jitter(), alpha=.1) +
     stat_smooth(method="glm", color="red", se=TRUE,
              method.args = list(family=binomial)) +
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
    theme_minimal() +
         labs(x='IV', y='Probability of DV base on IV', title='IV+Control as a Predictor of DV') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=20, face='bold'))
```

I get graphs, but I get the exact same plot no matter what I put in. I tried removing the control variable, and still get the exact same plots.